# Weird Javascript Calculation

Tags: javascript

Why when using javascript does this formula return `-Infinity`

`793 * ( 1 - ( 1 + Math.pow(.032 / 12 , (-1 * (30 * 12))))) / (.032 / 12);`

Comment: FWIW, at it's heart, you've got `Math.pow(smallFractionalNumber, negativeBigNumber)` leading to the initial `Infinity` - the rest is just noise

Comment: Exactly what @JamesThorpe said. Your Math.pow is roughly `4.4797768587048112310581443943723309108149091701091649 × 10^926` when plugged into Wolfram Alpha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's the correct answer!

The `Math.pow` part is equivalent to the following:

`Math.pow(0.0026666666666666666, -360)`

Which has  the result `Infinity`

Then, you multiply it by `-1`, and multiply / divide it by positive numbers, which doesn't affect the result considering it's `-Infinity`.

Answer (score 2):

The gist of it comes from `Math.pow(.032 / 12 , (-1 * (30 * 12)))`. You're taking a very small number (0.032/12) and taking it to a large, negative power (-1 * 30 * 12).

Mathematically, that's the same as taking a normal-sized number and taking it to a large number -- you're basically calculating `375**360`, which clearly is infinity. The rest of the numbers just end up making it `-Infinity` instead of `Infinity`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE),

> The MAX_VALUE property has a value of approximately 1.79E+308, or 21024. Values larger than MAX_VALUE are represented as "Infinity".

This part of your calculation `Math.pow(.032 / 12 , (-1 * (30 * 12)))` equals

> 4.4797768587048112310581443943723309108149091701091649 × 10^926

Which is larger than `Number.MAX_VALUE`, so it is represented as `Infinity`.
After that, you're basically just adding and flipping the sign.